# Why does text appear blurry when zooming in Safari until you release your fingers from the trackpad?

Tags: macos, safari, multi-touch

This has been bothering me for a while. When you zoom in Safari (Mac) using the pinch gesture, the text is only anti-aliased after finishing the gesture, not in realtime. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably to give a smoother and better user experience while browsing the web. If it did it in real time all systems wouldn't be able to handle it that well.

Comment: So AA is really that demanding? What a shame. I often zoom in for only half a second to read something and zoom out immediately afterwards without lifting my fingers, so it's a bit annoying.